# Why some applications can't convert between color models?

Tags: printer, colors

I get that different devices need different color models, as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/663576/why-do-color-printers-cameras-and-monitors-tvs-use-different-color-models), for example. However, why can't applications switch transparently between RGB and CMYK and send a RGB to a monitor and the equivalent CMYK to printers? What and why goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To create an RGB output and a CMYK output you have to set up the colors in a completely different way. So normally a programmer writes only code for RGB, this is often well supported by most APIs!
Second, you can't convert RGB and CMYK without loss. Look on this page:
https://www.printingforless.com/rgb-cmyk.html
for the graphics.
For some RGB values, you don't find an appropriate CMYK value.

So normally you have to set up both output types separately.